# Existence Uniqueness theorem for SDEs

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Is there a uniqueness and existence result for solutions to **systems** of Stochastic Differential Equations of diffusion type where coefficients are $\mathcal F_t$-measurable, i.e., could depend on the entire trajectories of processes up to time $t$?
$$dX_t=a_tdt+b_tdW_t, X_t \in \mathbb R^n$$
where $a_t, b_t$ are of appropriate dimensions and $\mathcal F_t$-measurable.

Most textbooks (e.g., Oksendal) provide theorems only for the cases when coefficients depend on the time $t$ values of stochastic processes, that is, $dX_t=a(t,X_t)dt+b(t,X_t)dW_t$.

Comment: Did you search in literatur for delayed SDEs?

Comment: No. But is there a general reference for such a theorem?

Comment: this could be a starting point: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.1726.pdf

Comment: I ask ny self whether there are results concerning existence and uniqueness when W is not Wiener but for example a continuous semimartingale or martingale